# Box2d:negative value return from GetLinearVelocity();

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

When I use the following, sometimes I get a negative value in mmVelik.x and mVelik.y.
Can anyone explain why??

```
b2Vec2 mVelik = ballBody->GetLinearVelocity();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value couldn't be negative, then objects would only be able to move in one direction. If the x value is positive, the velocity is toward the right, if it's negative, then toward the left. And ditto for the y value (down/up).